# COUNT column based on criteria, with one of the criterias being the newest date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to make a rapport that shows the number of different responses the different sellers get in excel

```
CustomerID  Respons Seller  Date
         1   YES    Jensen  08.08.2018
         1   NO     Chris   12.08.2018
         2   YES    Jensen  01.08.2018
         3   NO     Jensen  05.08.2018
```

If I have this dataset and I make a COUNT IFS function I get this

```
Seller Yes NO
Jensen 2   1
Chris  0   1
```

However since the costumer contacted us again and changed his yes to a no Jensens yes should be canceled out.

In my mind this would be easy to solve is the count only counts the newest respons if the same costumer contacts us again.

Sop the count should look like this

```
Seller Yes NO
Jensen 1   1
Chris  0   1
```

But I can not for the life of me figure this out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The CustomerID is different for the NO that Jensen receives.  If the CustomerID is different, how could Excel possibly know that it's the same customer and is now changing their mind?

Comment: If I am understanding this correctly, the same customer (#1) called back and got Chris, and gave Chris the no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the easiest way I can figure out how to do it, is create a helper column that displays the most recent answer.

This formula only works if the date is formatted as a date in Excel.

So you can make a 5th column with the following formula

```
 {=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF($A$2:$A$5=A2,IF($D$2:$D$5=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$5=A2,$D$2:$D$5,0)),$B$2:$B$5,""),""))}
```

This is an array formula, so you should enter it into the first cell of your list, then hit `ctrl+shift+enter` to submit the formula. Then you can copy and paste it as an array formula down the list.

To explain the formula,

1. `MAX(IF($A$2:$A$5=A2,$D$2:$D$5,0)` returns an array of all the dates the customer called in, then selects the most recent answer, and returns a 0 if false.
2. `IF($A$2:$A$5=A2,...` returns only the same customer, and returns a blank if false
3. `TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,....)`  removes all the blanks entries of the array, leaving just the latest answer.

After you have that helper column, you just need to only add a third criterion to your `COUNTIFS` statement. Your first criterion should be the name, the second, the logged response, and the third, the most recent response. That way it will only count if the logged response is equal to the final response. Which means Chris will get the no counted against him, while Jensen will not have the Yes or No counted on his part.

Comment: Hi, thank you so very much. this worked very well, but I discovered another problem. The software they use to logg responses will sometimes logg the same respons twice. Is there a way to not count theese duplicates?

Comment: A simple way would be to create a second helper column

Comment: A simple way would be to create a second helper column. Use a formula like `{=SUM(IF((A2=$A$2:$A$13)*(B2=$B$2:$B$13)*(C2=$C$2:$C$13)*(D2=$D$2:$D$13),1,0))}`. This formula counts idential instances. Then on your table, create a fourth `SUMIFS` criterion that counts only if the duplicate column is greater than 1.

Comment: Alternatively, you can highlight all the data, then use the Remove Duplicates (Data>Data Tools>Remove Duplicates) tool that is part Excel.